# Print out a variable in a Java servlet using output stream

Tags: java, servlets, stream

```
public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        //prints out my string
        resp.getOutputStream().write("Hello from servlet\n".getBytes());

        String variable ="VAR";
        //trying to print out variable by this way but doesn't work
        resp.getOutputStream().write("%s\n".getBytes(),variable);
        //doesn't work this way either
        resp.getOutputStream().write("variable is:"+ variable +"something else\n".getBytes());
    }
}
```

First, I was using `PageWriter out= resp.getWriter();` but then I switched to `ServletOutputStream` because I wanted to print images. Every thing else is OK but:

```
public void makedbconnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test");
    } catch(Exception idc) {
       //ON THIS LINE, out is ServletOutputStream.
       idc.printStackTrace(out);
    }
    //System.out.println("connection made");
}
```

Comment: Please, next time **explain** your problem with **text**, not only **code**. Also, when you are satisfied with an answer, **accept it**. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Obviously you can use `ServletOutputStream#print` but you could use [PrintWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29) as well.

```
resp.getWriter().print(yourvariable)
```

Answer (score 4):

`out` is a [ServletOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream.html). It has a rich set of overloaded `print()` methods. Just use

```
out.print(variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ServletOutputStream` has a large set of `print(...)` methods. When printing text, it's better to use them *instead* of `write(...)` ones.

Also, note that you can use `print` or `write` **multiple** times:

```
out.print("Hello, the variable is ");
out.print(variable);
out.println(". Something else?");
```

Notice that, instead of adding a `\n` in the end of the string, it's better to use `println`.